# linux random password generator - repeat n times

Tags: linux, security, bash

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=200 bs=1 2>/dev/null|tr "\n" " "|sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g'|cut -c-16
```

How do I repeat it set number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in `seq 10` ; do <your command here> ; done
```

it will repeat `<your command here>` 10 times.

Comment: Works xD       (15 characters)

Comment: @Phil: With Bash, it's not necessary to use `seq`. You can do `for i in {1..10}` or `for ((i=1;i<=10;i++))` and it saves forking another external executable.

Comment: @Dennis: Sure, you've right, but this job doesn't seem a time-critical task.

Answer (score 2):

If the point is to learn shell programming, see [cYrus's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/177019/linux-random-password-generator-repeat-n-times/177029#177029).

If the point is to generate a password, many distributions ship with [pwgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwgen/).